# Wiring issues with the Raspberry Pi Pico

Tags: relay, raspberry-pi-pico

I am having problems wiring a water pump with the Raspberry Pi Pico.

I have the pump connected to a relay which has IN connected to GPIO 12, GND connected to a ground pin, and VCC connected to VBUS. From the relay I have the NO connected to the battery positive and the COM is connected to the water pump positive. Note that the negative of the battery is connected to the negative of the pump.

I just recently asked for help with this question on stack overflow and have discovered it is a wiring issue after using a LED to find that the pin does turn off just for some reason the pump won't. Please help me with this issue.

Here is a wiring diagram

```
 +----------------+        +--------------+
 |                |        |              |
 |    Raspberry   |        |    Relay     |
 |       Pi       |        |    Board     |
 |      Pico      |        |              |
 |                |        |              |
 |                |        |              |
 |     VBUS (+5V) |------> | Input: VCC   |
 |                |        |              |
 |     GND        |------> | Input: GND   |
 |                |        |              |
 |     GPIO 12    |------> | Input: IN    |
 |                |        |              |
 |                |        |              |
 |                |        |  Output: NO  |-----> Battery (+)
 |                |        |              |
 |                |        |  Output: COM |-----> Water Pump (+)
 |                |        |              |
 +----------------+        +--------------+

Battery (-) -----> Water Pump(-)
```

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Please can you edit your question and add a schematic showing the existing circuit (not a photo of what you've made but an actual drawn schematic). Thanks.

Comment: Did you even try the suggestion in the stackoverflow question? I think the same question should not be open in two places, information rarely gets updated between them so double the effort wasted solving your problem.

Comment: @amlelephant please do not cross post and delete one of the questions

Answer (score 1):

The relay contacts are just a switch - they DO NOT supply power.

Assuming the pump requires 5 V, you need something like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2itqN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>